# javascript function return "undefine" from jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have a jsp page and call a JS function which is in some abc.js file from this JSP page.
i have included this js file to jsp page.

JSP JavaScript Code:-

```
function doFinish(tableId, col, field)
{
   var oldselectedCells = "";
   var selItemHandle = "";
   var selRightItemHandle = "";
   var left = -1;
   var right = -1;
   // Get the table (tBody) section
   var tBody = document.getElementById(tableId);
   // get field in which selected columns are stored
   var selectedCellsFld = document.getElementById(tableId + datatableSelectedCells);

   selectedCellsFld.value = oldselectedCells;
   for (var r = 0; r < tBody.rows.length; r++)
   {
      var row = tBody.rows[r];
      if (row.cells[col].childNodes[0].checked == true)
      {
         selectedCellsFld.value = oldselectedCells +
                                 row.cells[col].childNodes[0].id;
         selItemHandle = row.cells[col].childNodes[0].value

         oldselectedCells =  selectedCellsFld.value + datatableOnLoadDivider;

         left = selItemHandle.indexOf("=");
         right = selItemHandle.length;
         selRightItemHandle = selItemHandle.substring(left+1,right);
         var index=getColumnIndex(tBody,"Name");
         if(index!=null)
         {
            if(field == 1)
            {
               window.opener.document.TemplateForm.eds_asbactionscfg_item_handle_child_physpart.value = selRightItemHandle;
               window.opener.document.TemplateForm.ChildPhysicalPart.value = row.cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            }
            else if (field == 2)
            {
               window.opener.document.TemplateForm.eds_asbactionscfg_dev_doc_item_handle_name.value = selRightItemHandle;
               window.opener.document.TemplateForm.DeviationObject.value = row.cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            }
            else if (field == 3)
            {
               window.opener.document.TemplateForm.eds_asbactionscfg_dev_doc_item_handle_name.value = selRightItemHandle;
               window.opener.document.TemplateForm.DeviationObject.value = row.cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            }
         }

      }
   }

   window.close();
}
```

JS Code:-

```
function getColumnIndex(tBody,columnName)
 {
    var cells = tBody.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('th');     
    for (var i=0;i<cells.length; i++)
    {
       if(cells[i].hasChildNodes())
       {
          if(cells[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm ,"").trim() == columnName)
          {
             return i;
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

i had debug this code with firebug & calling `getColumnIndex(tBody,columnName)` function works fine but when it return to caller the `var index=getColumnIndex(tBody,"Name");` the index value is "undefine".

suggest some solution.

Comment: Can you show us what arguments you put into the function to cause it to return `undefined`?

Comment: i have a table:- doFinish('dtl_body_', 0, 1)

Comment: What is `tBody` and when/where it is ever defined?

Comment: var tBody = document.getElementById(tableId); it is define in doFinish()

Comment: Could you update the code in your question to show this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99890/discussion-between-nick-zuber-and-yogendra-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

`getColumnIndex(tBody,columnName)` function works fine. 
as if it matches this if condition

```
 if(cells[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm ,"").trim() == columnName)
          {
             return i;
          }
```

so that it returns something.

but when you replace this 
`var index=getColumnIndex(tBody,"Name");` so that coulmnName would be "Name" in String.
And it doesn't match with any columnName so that your condition going to be wrong and function doesn't return anything.

`var index=getColumnIndex(tBody,"Name");` the index value is "undefine".

suggestion is put some else condition on that and return some error message like this :

```
 if(cells[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm ,"").trim() == columnName)
          {
             return i;
          } else{
       // put some error message
       // return null   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i had debug this code with firebug & calling getColumnIndex(tBody,columnName) function works fine

From this, I'm assuming that there isn't anything wrong with the implementation of your `getColumnIndex` function, so your issue with getting an `undefined` value must have to do with *when* this function is returning a value.

> but when it return to caller the var index=getColumnIndex(tBody,"Name"); the index value is "undefine".

This leads me to assume that your `tBody` variable is not being set correctly, given that the "function works fine".

I'm assuming there is a case in your code where the conditions of your `getColumnIndex` function is not met.

```
function getColumnIndex(tBody,columnName)
 {
    var cells = tBody.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('th');     
    for (var i=0;i<cells.length; i++)
    {
       if(cells[i].hasChildNodes())
       {
          if(cells[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm ,"").trim() == columnName)
          {
             return i;
          }
       }
    }
    // If your code reaches this point, then the prior conditions have not been met
    // You can choose to do something else here for return false/undefined etc.
    return undefined;
 }
```

Comment: I said exactly the same.